# how to change actionscript 1-2 to actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

In flash, I created a button and gave the button this code (in AS1-AS2)

```
on (release)
{
    gotoAndPlay(5);
    tellTarget("/Anim") //'Anim' is just short form for 'an animation'

    {
        gotoAndPlay(5);
    } // End of TellTarget
}
```

Since you can't give specific buttons actions in AS3, I gave the button an instance name (the buttons instance name is now 'runButton') and then decided to do this in the actions layer.

```
runButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startAnimation);


function startAnimation(event:MouseEvent){

    gotoAndPlay(5);
    tellTarget("/Anim")
    {
        gotoAndPlay(5);
    } // End of TellTarget

}
```

but it is giving me an error saying that a '{' is expected after the

function startAnimation(event:MouseEvent):void{

line and it is saying that there is an unexpected '}' on the last line. Any idea how to fix this?

Note: Anim is a movieclip on the main timeline. When I double click the Anim movieclip, it has it's own timeline. I want that timeline to play along with the main timeline, hence the 'gotoandPlay(5) and then the other gotoAndPlay after doing 'tellTarget(Anim').

Comment: @ArlaudPierre hm, I removed void but now when I hit the button, it doesn't gotoAndPlay(5)

Comment: You need to add the event AFTER the function has been declared or it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Due to scope changes, AS1/AS2 whenever you called a function the regular scope of "this"-pointer was set to the object calling it, in as3, "this" referes to the movieclip owning runButton, so you bascially need to use `runButton.gotoAndPlay(5)` & `runButton.Anim.gotoAndPlay(5)`

Comment: @DanielMesSer runButton is a simple button. When I tried runButton.gotoAndPlay(5) it says that hotoAndPlay not found on flash.display.SimpleButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay found the answer, turns out I needed to change

```
tellTarget("/Anim") //'Anim' is just short form for 'an animation'

{
    gotoAndPlay(5);
} // End of TellTarget
```

to just

```
Anim.gotoAndPlay(5)
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Use "with" instead of tellTarget. But I do not recommend this at all.
Instead:

```
this[ "/Anim" ].gotoAndPlay(5);
```

Comment: Hm, when I do this it says 'A term is undefined and has no properties. at flashFile::MainTimeline/startAnimation()'

Comment: probably because /Anim is an invalid name for a display object. Probably is called Anim. Make sure it exists the moment you use that code.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Discipol's answer though I think you'll need to cast to a movie clip first:

```
MovieClip(this[ "/Anim" ]).gotoAndPlay(5);
```

Comment: hm, when I do this, it says 'Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. at flashFIle::MainTimeline/startAnimation'

Comment: is '/Anim' located at the root timeline? On further contemplation I believe the correct command would be: `MovieClip(this.getChildByName('/Anim')).gotoAndPlay(5)`

Comment: '/Amim' is located inside a sprite. Basically, when hitting the runButton, I want the timeline to play from 5 (gotoAndPlay(5)) and I want the sprite to play from it's timeline as well. The sprite is a graphic. (I'm actually at work debugging / switching a previous employees work from AS1-2 to AS3 so I don't fully understand what is going on but I'm trying to explain it the best way possible. Let me know if I'm unclear or if additional questions are needed to be answered.

Comment: oh wait, Anim is the name of a movie click on layer1 of the timeline, and if you double click the movie clip, it opens up it's own seperate timeline which should play from 5 seconds when the MovieClip(this.getChildByName('/Anim')).gotoAndPlay(5) line is executed, right? Or am I completely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`tellTarget` is deprecated since Flash 5. (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as2/reference/flashlite/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118cd9b5f6e-7a2b.html)

```
function startAnimation(event:MouseEvent):void{
    runButton.gotoAndPlay(5);

    //that slash in the beginning of name (/Anim) I have no idea what to do with, 
    //basically it used to tell a moveiclip named "/Anim" to "gotoAndPlay" however,
    //that is an invalid name so you probably have to change the name of it inside 
    //Flash unless I'm missing some kind of awesome legacy from old AS1/AS2.
    runButton.Anim.gotoAndPlay(5); 
}
runButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startAnimation);
```

Comment: Very true but this is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Depends what you mean, header says "change as1/as2 to as3", the question shows some legacy as1-code being used in as3 and the question also states a compiler error. Also, the code contains issues with this-scope since it isn't the same in AS3 as it were in older versions of AS.

Comment: @DanielMesSer Hm, when I do this, it gives an error saying "Property gotoAndPlay not found on flash.display.SimpleButton and there is no default value. at flashFile::MainTimeline/startAnimation()"

Comment: Aaah, so it is a SimpleButton, that means that it does not have an animation to "play" since it doesn't have a timeline. So simply omit that code line. Basically in AS1/AS2 everything on the stage was a movieclip, in AS3 that is not the case anymore. If you are using a SimpleButton that means that the view-states are handled internally inside the button. What ppl usually do is to either use the SimpleButton as it is or converting them into movieclips if you need more advanced behavior and then trigger any animation from code.

Comment: @DanielMesSer hmmm, Anim is a movie clip on layer1 of the main timeline. When I double click the Anim movieclip, it has it's own timeline, which I want to play when I hit runButton. (the Anim timeline should play along with the main timeline when the runButton is hit.)